# Update a spinner in Android

Tags: android, spinner

In my application I have 1 spinner option. In that I am displaying 6 values (which is array from values file). Now in that when I click its 5 items of the spinner value the selected item will show in the spinner in the activity screen.

When I select 6th item in spinner I have to start a new activity. Is it possible? Do I have to do this by position value?

Also in the new activity (after selecting 6th item) I have 5 edittext values in which user can enter a string which should replace the old value in the spinner. Is it possible to dynamically update the spinner?

My spinner code:

```
Spinner s2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
  this, R.array.group_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s2.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Comment: its possible [Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=spinner+in+android)

Comment: Are you sure you should implement this kind of functionality? Its better you share why you want to implement, so that someone here can suggest you the best way if possible.

Comment: Ya i want this funtionality.Y because in spinner value i have defined some predefined values,But this should be editable according to user choice.So only i have an edit option(6th option)in spinner,by which user can edit and save it to the spinner..

Answer (score 0):

It's possible

### Codings:

```
ArrayAdapter yearadp =  new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  yearlist);
            yearadp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

         year_spinner.setAdapter(yearadp);
    index=0;

     year_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
          spintext=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                if(spintext=="6")
                {
 intent        =    new Intent(ListMonthActivity.this,NewChart.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 }
  }
    }
```

Ya we can do with setting with

```
mon_spinner.setSelection(iSelectedMonth);
intent        =    new Intent(ListMonthActivity.this,NewChart.class);
```

You may or not mention while the action are certain action finished, and you can passed into another activity .

Comment: Thanks venkatesh..Is it possible to start an activity without taking the item..Is it possible do with position??

Comment: @Venkatesh setOnItemSelectedListener is not applicable to spinner

Comment: No @AkashG It's worked well in my activity. In my applcation i set the action depends on the selected item on the spinner items using setonitemselectedlistener.

Comment: it will give you error as  java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.

Comment: @prakash.k Do you check my coding now that's edited. Is it ok for you.If ok for you then accept my answer.

Comment: @Venkatesh its my fault.i was using setOnItemClickListener instead of setOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: Thanks Venkatesh..U have answer for my 2nd question.That is i have to upadate this spinner value.Is it possible??

Comment: @prakash.k Yes. First do it and then ask if it's not supported.

Comment: For 1st question problem is when i select 6th item it starts new activity,buy the spinner retaining the 6th value in the display.I dont want that i want to dispaly "Household" in the spinner..