# Spinner updation after an activity

Tags: android, spinner

In my application when user clicks an item in spinner it will go to new activity,in that i have 5 edit text ,in that i am retaining the value of spinner,When user edit this value and press save button ,the edited values should replace the old values in spinner.How can i achieve this??Please help me..

My spinner code:

```
 public class BudgetJulyo4Activity extends Activity
{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        DBadapter db =new DBadapter(this); 
        DBadapterRec dbrec=new DBadapterRec(this);
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {       

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);  
            Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            Button b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
            Button b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4); 
            Spinner s1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            Spinner s2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.recurr_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s1.setAdapter(adapter);        

            String group[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.group_array);------>Before calling edit(i.e when enters first time i am showing some hardcore value)

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,group);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s2.setAdapter(adapter1);    
}

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) ------>After edit option.
        {      
            java.lang.System.out.println("Inside act");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
//      }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);        
            if(resultCode==1)
            {          
                 Spinner s2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                String str1=data.getStringExtra("grp1val");    
                String str2=data.getStringExtra("grp2val");  
                String str3=data.getStringExtra("grp3val");
                String str4=data.getStringExtra("grp4val"); 
                String str5=data.getStringExtra("grp5val");  
                String str6="Edit";

                String group[] = new String[] { str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6};
                 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,group);               
                adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                s2.setAdapter(adapter1);                

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a spinner in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498873/update-a-spinner-in-android)

Comment: @prakash : start SpinnerEdit as `startactivityforresult` instead of `startActivity` and use `setResult` in `SpinnerEdit` Activity for sending data back to Spinner Activity.then in `startactivityforresult` you can reset Spinner value selected by user in `SpinnerEdit` Activity.

Comment: @prakash.k why are you post same question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try as start SpinnerEdit Activity as `startactivityforresult` instead of `startActivity` for getting user saved value Back in Spinner Activity and then you can upadte Spinner with latest Values in `startactivityforresult`  :

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> s2, View arg1,
    int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    group=s2.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    if(group.equals("Edit"))
      {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SpinnerEdit.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
      }
      //your code here...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==1){
           String str1=ata.getStringExtra("grp1val");
           ...
           //here you can update your Spinner Adapter with latest values
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

and in SpinnerEdit:

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent spin = new Intent();
    spin.putExtra("grp1val", group1.getText().toString()); 
    spin.putExtra("grp2val", group2.getText().toString()); 
    spin.putExtra("grp3val", group3.getText().toString()); 
    spin.putExtra("grp4val", group4.getText().toString()); 
    spin.putExtra("grp5val", group5.getText().toString());
    setResult(1,spin);
    finish();
  }
});
```

Comment: HI imran i want to pass to another activity in back button in spinneredit class.This is my following code:                         Intent spin=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BudgetJulyo4Activity.class);
     spin.putExtra("grp1val", group1.getText().toString());
     spin.putExtra("grp2val", group2.getText().toString());
     spin.putExtra("grp3val", group3.getText().toString());
     spin.putExtra("grp4val", group4.getText().toString());
     spin.putExtra("grp5val", group5.getText().toString());
     startActivityForResult(spin, 1);.But it is not going into activityonresult code..

Comment: use setResult instead of startActivityForResult in SpinnerEdit Activity

Comment: @prakash.k : which adapter you are using currently for filling data in Spinner?

Comment: This is the spinner populating code before going to edit options:     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.group_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
         adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         s2.setAdapter(adapter1);

Comment: try  `adapter1.add("new value");` in `startActivityForResult` and you can find lots of example how we update ArrayAdapter by code on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @prakash.k : see this post maybe helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828675/dynamic-add-data-to-spinner-but-not-update-the-data-on-the-spinner

Comment: one more thing you have static array so it's not possible to remove values from xml file ok. then you have one option get xml array as ArrayList then use ArrayList as data source for Spinner then you can easy update,delete or remove items from spinner

Comment: get string-array in Array a `String[] albums = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.code1_array);` then set it to spinner adapter as data source. you can easily update,delete or modifies array

Comment: Ya i changed:This is b4 edit   String group[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.group_array);ArrayAdapter<String>adapter1 =newArrayAdapter<Stringthis,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,group);adapter1.setDropDownViewResource android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) s2.setAdapter(adapter1);  This is after edit:String group[] = new String[] { str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6}; ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,group);adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s2.setAdapter(adapter1);

Comment: But tyhe problem i am facing is now the list get updated when i go to edit option>but when i come first time the adapter with resource file is showing,it should not show like that,whatever i uodated should remail there instead of previous..

Comment: @prakash.k : sorry can you explain it more

Comment: Imran now see my edited post.In that when my app starts i show spinner with some value,and once the user edit that it updated in the spinner.Now when i close the app and once again i run the app means the spinner with default value is coming not with the updated.Because update happens only edit is done,so the default valu from resource is showing.

Comment: @prakash.k : last step use sharedpreference to store user seleted values and check sharedpreference  for null in oncreate of Activity if sharedpreference   value is null then fill adapter from xml file otherwise fill Adapter from  sharedpreference

Answer (score 1):

If the adapter of your Spinner extends BaseAdapter then you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it after the data has been modified:

```
((BaseAdapter)s2.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I tried this then i got this exception                                                         07-16 12:59:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: can you see in the exception's traces where it happens in your code ?

Comment: final ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  month);
  NoCoreAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);                                                      mon_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
           int index=0;
           NoCoreAdapter.add("EDIT");
           ((BaseAdapter) mon_spinner.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
I will send my LOGcat below this

Comment: 07-16 13:14:07.198: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(604): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
07-16 13:14:07.198: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(604):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:411)
07-16 13:14:07.198: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(604):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:432)
07-16 13:14:07.198: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(604):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:178)
07-16 13:14:07.198: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(604):     at com.experts.IVScreen.ListMonthActivity$1.onItemSelected(ListMonthActivity.java:87)

Answer (score 1):

use `s2.setselection(position)` in setOnItemSelectedListener and save that value in shared preference and use above method in oncreate of that activity

Comment: Thanks Praveena_Pinki .. But I am not up to that level in android..Can you please give some detail for the above answer you posted...